# What happened to middlegen and what do I use today instead?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, pojo

I have an older java application.  It used hibernate and middlegen to create its classes.  If I were to create the pojos today using hibernate.  What would I use for a code generator?  The middlegen website is dead, and I only saw on sourceforge something for Maven.  Everything else is just gone.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Hibernate-tools extensions available for Eclipse.

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use AndroMDA http://www.andromda.org/index.html - It generates Code (Java, PHP, .NET,...) from UML Models (as XML Files).
You can choose to generate code for Hibernate, EJB, Spring, WebServices, and Struts or write own plugins.

It is a nice tool if you can get it running.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The author asked " If I were to create the pojos today using hibernate. What would I use for a code generator?" - AndroMDA generates classes & hibernate schema. Please leave me a comment why you think that this is not a legit answer to the question.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I agree with Manuel that this is a valid answer. AndroMDA is a tool that can be used to generate artifacts (entities among other types) from, for example, UML diagrams.

Comment: @ManuelM It's a valid answer, but you should expand your answer on what you are linking to, what it does, and why it relates to the question. That will misunderstandings. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, "Provide context for links"

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDE for that, e.g. [Intellij Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jpa_hibernate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/. This might be what you looking for.

Comment: this cannot generate classes - it is nice to reverse engineer an existing database though.